# How to compute palindrome from a stream of characters in sub-linear space/time?

Tags: algorithm, stream, puzzle, palindrome

I don't even know if a solution exists or not. Here is the problem in detail. You are a program that is accepting an infinitely long stream of characters (for simplicity you can assume characters are either 1 or 0). At any point, I can stop the stream (let's say after N characters were passed through) and ask you if the string received so far is a palindrome or not. How can you do this using less sub-linear space and/or time.

Comment: A couple thoughts.  In every palindrome, the counts of all characters are even, except that in odd-length palindromes the middle character has an odd count.  Also, if the last input was a palindrome, the next input cannot be a palindrome unless there is only one unique character in the string.  You can use these to answer "no" quickly in some cases, but I can't think of a way to improve the asymptotic complexity beyond O(n) time, space.

Comment: I can understand wanting to use less than O(n) space, but O(n) time seems odd, since you need to do something about n characters individually.  Do you mean less than O(n) time once the stream is stopped?

Comment: @David: I think that's what he means yes, @wrick: I'd be hard pressed to use sub-linear space. The input stream might be random (up to its half) and still be a palindrome, therefore it has up to N/2 characters of entropy which would require O(N) space. I may be wrong of course.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  The answer is about two-thirds of the way down http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/stringology-the-real-string-theory/

**EDIT:** Some people have asked me to summarize the result, in case the link dies.  The link gives some details about a proof of the following theorem: *There is a multi-tape Turing machine that can recognize initial non-trivial palindromes in real-time.*  (A summary, also provided by the article linked: Suppose the machine has read *x1, x2, ..., xk* of the input.  Then it has only constant time to decide if *x1, x2, ..., xk* is a palindrome.)

A multitape Turing machine is just one with several side-by-side tapes that it can read and write to; in a very specific sense it is exactly equivalent to a standard Turing machine.

A real-time computation is one in which a Turing machine must read a character from input at least once every M steps (for some bounded constant M).  It is readily seen that any real-time algorithm should be linear-time, then.

There is a paper on the proof which is around 10 pages which is available behind an institutional paywall [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01404109) which I will not repost elsewhere.  You can contact the author for a more detailed explanation if you'd like; I just had read this recently and realized it was more or less what you were looking for.

Comment: Seems interesting, but more details please. Real time does not seem to preclude storing the input. What I gathered was that, once you see the end of the string, you can tell if it is a palindrome in O(1) time (which is quite an amazing result!). +1 anyway :-)

Comment: Great read, but he does not give the algorithm there in his article, just says a 2-tape Turing Machine can do it in O(1) time.

Comment: @drvitek: links tend to die, when it does, your answer will be useless... could you sum up the article in a few lines or demonstrate the algorithm (perhaps just its idea) ?

Comment: wrick: Yes, but he links to a paper which can be read in a journal or requested from the author which gives more details.  @Matthieu: Done.  @Moron: It does not; however, if I recall correctly it implies that the space requirements are also linear.

Comment: Is it just an existence proof or does someone actually have such an algorithm?

Comment: @drvitek: Thanks :) Now we have the idea so we can start searching ^^

Comment: @drvitek: So you are claiming we cannot do a streaming palindrome check in sublinear space? That does not seem obvious...

Comment: @Moron.  I did not say that; I said that the space requirements for *this* algorithm are linear.  (That wasn't completely clear, however, so please don't interpret this as an angry comment; simply a clarification.  Also, I appear to have replied incorrectly to your earlier comment.  You are correct in all of your points in your first comment; real-time does not preclude storing the input.  I didn't make this clear in my first reply.)

Comment: @drvitek: No worries. I just wanted to confirm that the question of sub-linear space is still open (on stackoverflow i.e.)

Comment: @Aryabhatta I think Matthieu M.'s comment to the original question shows that sub-linear space is impossible -- you might be able to achieve better with an approximate or probabilistic algorithm though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [rolling hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash), or more rolling hashes for accuracy. Incrementally compute the hash of the characters read so far, in the order they were read, and in reverse order of reading.

If your hash function is `x*3^(k-1)+x*3^(k-2)+...+x*3^0` for example, where `x` is a character you read, this is how you'd do it:

```
hLeftRight = 0
hRightLeft = 0
k = 0

repeat until there are numbers in the stream
    x = stream.Get()    

    hLeftRight = 3*hLeftRight + x.Value
    hRightLeft = hRightLeft + 3^k*x.Value

    if (x.QueryPalindrome = true)
        yield hLeftRight == hRightLeft

    k = k + 1
```

Obviously you'd have to calculate the hashes modulo something, probably a prime or a power of two. And of course, this could lead to false positives.

Comment: Doesn't "reverse order of reading" require you to store the characters? And I guess this is not deterministic... If you want probabilistic, you could randomly store, say n^0.9 characters (and their positions), and see if we can detect a palindrome in what we stored...

Comment: @Moron - you don't have to store the characters because the hash function is a polynomial, so you can build both hashes incrementally. You're right that it's probabilistic. If you store random characters however, wouldn't that lead to a lot of false positives and even false negatives? I would say this is more accurate, and uses less memory.

Comment: Actually, your k is increasing like n and so computing 3^k might require linear space! And if you do this modulo some number, you will have collisions and false postives/negatives. Which is better is hard to say without doing the computations. Of course I am not claiming what I suggested is better :-)

Comment: @Moron - why would exponentiation require linear space? And if the hashes are different, then there is no way the string so far is a palindrome. So you can only get false positives with this, not false negatives.

Comment: @Moron - you compute the hashes modulo a constant prime number or power of 2, so there's no `n` involved. If you don't compute them modulo something, then this is deterministic, but linear in space like you say.

Comment: @IVlad: Yes and that would lead to collisions and to decide if it is good, we would actually need to do computations :-)

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the probability of false positives is, and how this probability changes with the addition of more hash functions. Unfortunately, I don't know how to go about computing this. It might turn out to be small enough to be negligible for practical purposes however. Although this question doesn't sound too practical, so... :).

Answer (score 0):

Round 2

As I see it, with each new character, there are three cases:

1. Character breaks potential symmetry, for example, aab -> aabc
2. Character extends the middle, for example aab -> aabb
3. Character continues symmetry, for example aab->aaba

Assume you have a pointer that tracks down the string and points to the last character that continued a potential palindrome.

(I am going to use parenthesis to indicate a pointed at character)

Lets say you are starting with aa(b) and get an:

- 'a' (case 3), you move the pointer to
  the left and check if it's an 'a' (it
  is). You now have a(a)b.
- 'c' (case 1), you are not expecting a 'c', in this case you start back at the beginning and you now have aab(c).

The really tricky case is 2, because somehow you have to know that the character you just got isn't affecting symmetry, it is just extending the middle. For this, you have to hold an additional pointer that tracks where the plateau's (middle's) edge lies. For example, you have (b)baabb and you just got another 'b', in this case you have to know to reset the pointer to the base of the middle plateau here: bbaa(b)bb. Since we are going for constant time, you have to hold a pointer here to begin with (you can't afford the time to search for the plateau's edge). Now if you get another 'b', you know that you are still on the edge of that plateau and you keep the pointer where it is, so bbaa(b)bb -> bbaa(b)bbb. Now, if you get an 'a', you know that the 'b's are not part of the extended middle and you reset both pointers (The tracking pointer and the edge pointer) so you now have bbaabbbb((a)).

With these three cases, I think all bases are covered. If you ever want to check if the current string is a palindrome, check if the first pointer (not the plateau's edge pointer) is at index 0.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you:
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3466v1.pdf

If you store the last $k$ many input symbols you can easily find palindromes up to a length of $k$.
If you use the algorithms of the paper you can find the midpoints of palindromes and an length estimate of its length.